# Shell redirection - dialog

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I cannot interpret the code blow

```
exec 3>&1
INTERFACE=`echo $DIALOG_TAGS | xargs dialog --title 'Test' --menu ' Text comes here :' 0 0 0 2>&1 1>&3`
exec 3>&-
: > $TMPDIR/._tmp.conf
```

My question is; FD#3 is created with `exec 3>&1` and redirected to where FD#1 goes. In the second line, we have `2>&1 1>&3` which confuses me.

Another part is the last line, where `:` and a `>` redirection take place.

Any explanations will be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exec 3>&1
```

FD #3 is created, writing to FD #1 (`stdout`).

```
INTERFACE=`echo $DIALOG_TAGS | xargs dialog --title 'Test' --menu ' Text comes here :' 0 0 0 2>&1 1>&3`
```

The command in backtics is executed. (In this case, a `dialog` menu displaying the tag / item pairs defined in `DIALOG_TAGS`.)

The FD #2 (`stderr`) is redirected to FD #1 (`stdout`, which gets assigned to `INTERFACE` due to the backticks). The FD #1 (`stdout`) is redirected to FD #3.

The idea is as follows:

- `dialog` displays a menu from which you can select an item. The menu, obviously, needs `stdout` to write to. The *result* (selection) from the menu is, by default, written to `stderr`.
- The author wants to *capture* the result, thus he redirects `stderr` to `&1` so the result ends up in `INTERFACE`.
- However he wants *only* the result, not the whole menu... so instead of capturing the menu *and* the result, he *redirects* the menu (`stdout`) to the previously-created *copy* of `stdout`, leaving only the *result* to be sent to FD #1, and thus stored in `INTERFACE`, while the menu is being displayed via the FD #3 (which is still pointing to the terminal, regardless of the backticks).

Once that is done...

```
exec 3>&-
```

FD #3 is closed, as it is no longer needed.

---

```
: > $TMPDIR/._tmp.conf
```

This, I couldn't understand. The colon is a builtin command that does nothing, except parameter expansion and redirection. It creates an empty file...? Perhaps to indicate to some other program that the selection is made...? Or to preserve the time stamp...? No idea.

Comment: Thanks! I am not clear at this point >> The FD #2 (`stderr`) is redirected to FD #1 (`stdout`, which gets assigned to `INTERFACE` due to the backticks). The FD #1 (`stdout`) is redirected to FD #3. .... The INTERFACE=`....` part is fine, but to my understanding, `stdout` of backticks block has already been redirected to FD#3, so cannot figure out how we are able to capture `stdout` while it has already been redirected?

Comment: @FehmiNoyanISI: Ha-ha, got 'cha. :-) Shell redirection is remarkably un-intuitive that way. `2>&1` redirects FD #2 to where FD #1 is pointing *at that moment*. That does not mean that FD #2 is now *included* in FD #1, it is merely *redirected* to its *target*. And if the line goes on with `1>&3`, that means that FD #1 is now redirected to where FD #3 is pointing *at that moment* (i.e., `stdout`), while FD #2 is *still* pointing where FD #1 was pointing *at the point FD #2 was redirected*. --- This takes a while getting used to. ;-)